# Python DataFrame loop and slice issue

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, slice

```
import random
import re
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Greetings": ["Greetings to you too", "hi", "hello", "hey", "greetings", "sup", "what's up", "yo"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Farewell": ["GoodBye", "see you", "bye", "laters"]})

frames = [df1, df2]
df3=pd.concat(frames, axis=1, join='outer', copy=True)
def check_for_greet():
 while True:
    try:
        sentence = input("Start chatting:  ")
        wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  sentence).split()
        if sentence == "$$$":
                return "END"

        for word in wordList:
            for col in df3.columns:
                if word.lower() in df3[col].values:
                    print (df3[col][0])
                    break
```

The above works perfectly now between columns (thank you @R.yan), only issue however is when I type "hi hi', it prints it twice:

```
Start chatting:  hi hi
Greetings to you too
Greetings to you too
```

Why is it doing that, I am breaking the for loop with continue to return to the while loop?!

Answer (score 2):

Replace your function with following:

```
def check_for_greet():
 while True:
    try:
        sentence = input("Start chatting:  ")
        wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  sentence).split()
        if sentence == "$$$":
                return "END"

        for col in df3.columns:
            if sentence.lower() in df3[col].values:
                print df3[col][0]
        continue
```

**Output:**

```
Start chatting:  hi
Greetings to you too
Start chatting:  bye
GoodBye
```

---

**answer for your duplicated output**

```
word_found = False
for word in wordList:          
    for col in df3.columns:
        if word.lower() in df3[col].values:
            print (df3[col][0])
            word_found = True
    if word_found:
        break
```

Comment: There is an issue with this code, It works only for "bye". However, when I input "see you", it gives me "Greetings to you too". What it should be doing is if I input anything as "hi", "hello", "hey", "greetings", "sup", "what's up", "yo", to give me "Greetings to you too". And any input of "see you", "bye", "laters", to give me output of "GoodBye". Your suggested code does not do that :(

Comment: @Muke888 Ops, sorry. Didn't notice that. I have changed the answer above. Actually, do not need to use `iterrows` to make the thing complicated.

Comment: Thanks R.yan! It is almost complete now, only issue I am having is that it duplicates the output when it shouldn't! I updated the post, could you please help?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The duplicates output is due to you are looping the word list. Add a `break` to stop the loop if you find the word.

Comment: @ Muke888 My answer above has updated to fix your duplicated output.

Comment: No problem:) That's great:D